# Delay loading UIView until mapkit loads

Tags: objective-c, ios, location, mapkit, coordinates

I have a question regarding MapKit in iOS. I have 3 screens.First screen(master view),Second screen(detail view) and third screen(extending second screen). So i click master view and go to detail view.Here in detail view i have a map kit. So when i first move from 1->2 it is doing fast and not able to load mapkit. I get the location but in a world map view. But i go back to first screen and back to second screen then it is showing the area around my location in a zoomed in mode with a blue dot. So my question is, is there a function   that will set the zoom in and then load my UIview.Basically, halt till the map triangulates the user location and then when done show the zoomed in mode and the rest of the view.? If more information is needed please let me know...Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the map's visibleRegion/visibleMapRect at load time?

Comment: @tc. Yes i set this line in my viewWillAppear. [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES]; is this what you are asking for?

Comment: And what is viewRegion set to?

Comment: @tc #define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344 MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5 *METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);. Also, can i get a zoom icon (+ ,-) to zoom in or out in map kit.If yes,how?

Comment: Updating your question with the code would be more helpful — I have no idea what "zoomLocation" is set to. However, it seems likely that you are trying to zoom into the user's "current location" at view load, which isn't available until a few seconds later; consider setting `MKMapView.userTrackingMode` or implementing the `-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a way to do that you still probably shouldn't. It may take quite while to get the user's location and you wouldn't want your app to be stuck until then. The most you could do is load the mapview and start it triangulating but cover it with another view which shows a progress indicator> Set up a delegate to get a call back when a location is found and if it is accurate enough for your purposes, hide the top view and show the map that was hidden underneath.